Debug Console commands with cppvsdbg debugging in vscode
If I am debugging a c++ program in Visual Studio code with gdb I have full access to all the gdb commands through the "Debug Console"
This is documented on the code website (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug):
"For the C++ (GDB/LLDB) debugging environment, you can execute GDB, LLDB and LLDB-MI commands directly through the debug console with the -exec command, but be careful, executing commands directly in the debug console is untested and might crash VS Code in some cases."
For example if I have
std::vector<double> xy = {1,2,3,4,5};
Then I can type:
-exec print xy
and I will get:
$1 = std::vector of length 5, capacity 5 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Which is a single string that contains all the information about xy.
Is there a Visual Studio Windows Debugger equivalent of the GDB commands that can be typed into the "Debug Console" of the Visual Studio Code IDE when debugging c++?
By experimentation I have found that I can just type in a variable name I can get access to that variable.
I can type "xy" into the debug console it prints "{ size=5 }" which I can click on and it will expand out to reveal the contents of xy. This is the same behavior as the "Watch" and "Variables" Panes and is not what I'm looking for. I want to type a single command and get all the contents of the variable, even if it is in a different from than the string I get from gdb.
